# Quickest way to rate takes in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe

How do you rate a series of takes in Premiere?
I'd like to be able to look at a series of takes, and quickly mark each one out of 5 or 10, using the keyboard more than the mouse... Is there a good way to do this?
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to adjust the metadata display. In the panel menu of the project panel, select the option **Metadata display**. In the Metadata Display window, activate the **Rating** display under **Basic**. This way, you get your five-star rating system right in the project panel (you can change the position of the rating column using drag-and-drop). Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to assign shortcuts to this star rating system.

Another option, if you are dead set on primarily working with the keyboard, are label colors. You can change the available label colors in the program preferences. You could, for example, use a color code as your rating system (e.g. green → blue → yellow → orange → red). Then, you can assign shortcuts to these colors: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to bring up the Keyboard Shortcuts window. The color shortcuts can be found under **Edit** → **Label**.